# Custom Fonts not being applied windows phone8/8.1

Tags: silverlight

When i tried to apply custom fonts for TextBlock in silverlight for windows phone, some fonts are getting applied where as some being not applied and default font is getting applied.

We are using the following line to set the font
txtblk1.FontFamily = new System.Windows.Media.FontFamily("/CustomFonts/HelveticaNeueLTArabic-Bold.ttf#HelveticaNeueLT Arabic 75 Bold");

font file is copied to CustomFonts folder with build action set to content and copyalways true.